# Error installing therubyracer on osx 10.12.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xcode, macos, gcc, therubyracer

I have gone through a lot of answers on a similar questions but I have not been successful. I am trying to install therubyracer 0.12.3 on my MAC OSX 10.12.4 and I am receiving the following error. Please help. Been stuck with this for two days now.

> sudo gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.3'
>
> Building native extensions. 
>   This could take a while... ERROR:  Error installing therubyracer:
>     ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
> current directory: /Users/aj035785/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.3/ext/v8
> ```
>
> /Users/aj035785/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby -r
>   ./siteconf20170420-2619-13h8man.rb extconf.rb checking for main() in
>   -lpthread... yes checking for main() in -lobjc... yes creating Makefile
>
> current directory:
>   /Users/aj035785/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.3/ext/v8
>   make "DESTDIR=" clean
>
> current directory:
>   /Users/aj035785/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.3/ext/v8
>   make "DESTDIR=" compiling accessor.cc make:
>   /usr/local/opt/apple-gcc42/bin/g++-4.2: No such file or directory
>   make: *** [accessor.o] Error 1
>
> make failed, exit code 2
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /Users/aj035785/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.3
>   for inspection. Results logged to
>   /Users/aj035785/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-16/2.3.0/therubyracer-0.12.3/gem_make.out
>   Blockquote

I feel this might be the root cause - 
make: /usr/local/opt/apple-gcc42/bin/g++-4.2: No such file or directory

Comment: Do you have XCode and its Command Line Tools installed? Did you accept its license agreement?

Comment: @spickermann yes i have xcode 8.3.2 and installed Command Line Tools with xcode-select --install